# Pass more than one parameters to iterator function for array helper method in ES6

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm learning typescript, about array helper and pass to iterator function,
I have code below

```
var cars = [
  { model: 'Suzuki', price: 'Normal' },
  { model: 'Honda', price: 'Expensive' },
  { model: 'Daihatsu', price: 'Cheap' },
  { model: 'Toyota', price: 'Expensive' }
]

const p10 = (n) => {
  return n.price === 'Expensive'
}

var resultCar = cars.filter(p10)
console.log('p10 : ',resultCar)
```

above code will return 2 objects `Honda` and `Toyota`,
my question is how do I pass `'Expensive'` as parameters to iterator function `p10`
I don't want to hard code `'Expensive'` inside iterator function `p10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can curry your `p10` function so that you can pass through your `price` first, and then return the comparison function which uses the initial passed through `price` argument like so:

```js
const cars = [{ model: 'Suzuki', price: 'Normal' }, { model: 'Honda', price: 'Expensive' }, { model: 'Daihatsu', price: 'Cheap' }, { model: 'Toyota', price: 'Expensive' }];

const p10 = price => n => n.price === price;

const resultCar = cars.filter(p10("Expensive"));
console.log('p10 : ', resultCar);
```